# A Puzzle Consisting Entirely of Reused Information

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge

In the spirit of [A Puzzle Consisting Entirely of Random Anagrams](http://web.mit.edu/puzzle/www/2015/puzzle/a_puzzle_consisting_entirely_of_random_anagrams/), I decided to make my own puzzle.

```
informatiinformainformatinfinforminfoininininformationinformainformatiinformat informatiinformainformatinformatinformationinfinformationinfoinformatioinformationinfinformationinform
informatiinformainformatinformationinfinformatioinforminfininformaininfoinfo informatiinformainformatinformationininformatinformatioinformatioinformainfinfoinformain
informatiinformainformatinformationinfoinforinformatiinforminformatiinformatioininformatiinfor informatiinformainformatinformatioinfoinformationinforinforinformatiininformainformain informatiinformainformatinformatioinfinformatioinformainformatiinformationinfoinformatiinformain informatiinformainformatinformatioinformatininforminfoinforminforminfoinfoinformatio
informatiinformainformatinformatioinfinformationinfinfinformatiinformatioinfoinformationinformat informatiinformainformatinformationinfinformatioinforminfinforinfoininformationinformati informatiinformainformatinformatioinformatinformatioinfinformatiininformationinfininformatio
informatiinformainformatinformatioinfoinfinforinfoinformininformatioinformatioinformatio informatiinformainformatinformationinformationinformationinformatinforinformatinforinformainformainformation informatiinformainformatinformatioinfoinformationinforininformationinforinformatioinfoinform
informatiinformainformatinformationinformatinfoinfoinformatinformatioinformationinformatioinformatioinformat informatiinformainformatinformatioinformainfoinformatinformainfinforminformationinformatioin
informatiinformainformatinformatioinformainfoinformatinformainformatiinformatioinformatinforin informatiinformainformatinformatioinforininformationininformationinformatioinininfor
informatiinformainformatinformatioinfoinformatinforminforminformatininformationinformatioinfor
informatiinformainformatinformationinformatinfoinformationinforinformatioinformatioinforminformationinfo informatiinformainformatinformatioinfoinformationinforinfinfinforininformationinformat
informatiinformainformatinformatioinforinfinformatinfoinforminformatiinfininform informatiinformainformatinformatioinformainforminformatioinformatioinfoinformatiinfoinforminfo informatiinformainformatinformatioinformatininfoinformainformainformainfinformatiinfor
informatiinformainformatinformatioinforininformationinfoinformatiinformatiinformainformationin informatiinformainformatinformatioinformatininforminfoinforinformatinforminforinformatio
```

Comment: I don't really think this fits in [the current FTC](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6458/fortnightly-topic-challenge-38-reusing-information-1) despite its appearance, but others can judge after it's solved.

Comment: I laughed out loud.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Step 1:

> By inspecting the strings it should be evident that they are entirely composed of substrings (to be a stronger statement, they are all prefix strings) of the word "information". Perhaps we should track how long these prefixes are.   We get:
>
> ```
>  9783642221798 9788131401316
>  9781306327244 9781280073472
>  9781459690295 9780415592772 9780307914972 9780826466440
>  9780313390418 9781306354219 9780803921320
>  9780435462000 9781118585771 9780415215046
>  9781844801008 9780748736102
>  9780748790852 9780521210225
>  9780486682105
>  9781841500614 9780415335218
>  9780538469326 9780760049464 9780824777395
>  9780521499712 9780826458650
> ```
>
> (I've replaced the 10 and 11 letter strings "informatio" and "information" with 0 and 1 respectively.)

Step 2:

> We notice that these numbers are all 13 digits long, and start with 978. This strongly suggests that these are ISBN numbers, which can be confirmed by googling the numbers. So we find all of these book titles:
>
> ```
>  9783642221798 9788131401316
>  Green IT: Technologies and Applications
>  IT; Technologies and Products
>  
>  9781306327244 9781280073472
>  Science and Information Theory: Second Edition
>  ICT: Changing Education
>  
>  9781459690295 9780415592772 9780307914972 9780826466440
>  Teaching Early Years Mathematics, Science and ICT
>  The Really Useful ICT Book
>  The Information Audiobook
>  ICT in the Early Years
>  
>  9780313390418 9781306354219 9780803921320
>  Information and Information Systems
>  Information Theory
>  Information Theory: Structural Models for Qualitative Data
>  
>  9780435462000 9781118585771 9780415215046
>  Edexcel AS GCE Applied ICT Single Award 
>  Elements of Information Theory
>  Teaching and Learning Using ICT in the Primary School
>  
>  9781844801008 9780748736102
>  Data Processing and Information Technology
>  Understanding Information Technology
>  
>  9780748790852 9780521210225
>  ICT Framework Solutions Year 7
>  The Physics of Information Technology
>  
>  9780486682105
>  An Introduction to Information Theory
>  
>  9781841500614 9780415335218
>  ICT for Curriculum Enhancement
>  Quality Issues in ICT-Based Higher Education (The Staff and Educational Development Series)
>  
>  9780538469326 9780760049464 9780824777395
>  Accounting Information Systems: Foundations in Enterprise Risk Management
>  Management Information Systems
>  Handbook of Information Resource Management (Public Administration and Public Policy)
>  
>  9780521499712 9780826458650
>  Logic and Information
>  The Role of ICT
> ```

Step 3:

> Hopefully it should be fairly obvious that the titles of the books have a fairly repetitive motif: the word information appears a lot. And in the titles that don't, they often talk about ICT (which is short for Information and Communications Technology) or IT. Combined with the fact that each line contains one to four titles, perhaps we should consider Morse code, with acronyms being dots and fully-written "information" being dashes. This gives us:
>
> ```
> .. -. ..-. --- .-. -- .- - .. --- -.
> ```
>
> ... which... translates to... **INFORMATION**.

Comment: (funny bonus content: if we reapply the encodings used in steps 3 and 1 to the final answer, we get a puzzlehunt that's happening soon: rot13(QNFU 11).)

Comment: Nice work! Sorry that I wasn’t able to congratulate you at the same time as giving the check mark, internet was a bit dodgy. (Also unsurprisingly the bonus content was not intended.)